# Python video game controller script

Tags: python

Hey there new to python and trying some cool projects.

I am currently playing maple story on a private sever and trying to create a script to automate some tedious tasks such as looting items or use buffs. For some reason when ever I run the script the client can't detect the key strokes from script and I am not sure why. I have tried testing the script on other programs, ie notepad and Starbound and it works fine. So I am not sure why this specific client won't detect the key strokes. Any suggestions would me greatly appreciated.

I have also pasted sample code of what I am trying to test, got some source code from  another post on stack overflow. I have also tried using the the pyautogui,and pynput libraries all with the same results.

```
import win32api
import win32gui
import ctypes
import time
SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput

# C struct redefinitions 
PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)
class KeyBdInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
                ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)]

class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
                ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time",ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("ki", KeyBdInput),
                 ("mi", MouseInput),
                 ("hi", HardwareInput)]

class Input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("ii", Input_I)]

# Actuals Functions

def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008 | 0x0002, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

# directx scan codes http://www.gamespp.com/directx/directInputKeyboardScanCodes.html
time.sleep(3)

for i in range(3):
    print(win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(ord('D'))) # used to check if keys are being pressed.
    PressKey(0x20)
    print(win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(ord('D')))
    ReleaseKey(0x20)
    print(win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(ord('D')))
```

Thanks for taking look.

Comment: That program possibly uses XInput or some other input-management mechanism that sidesteps window messages.

Comment: is there a way to bypass that, or put another version of input to be able to read window messages? Also the game responds to the OSK so how is that different from a virtual key stroke?

Answer (score 0):

can you try converting it to exe file and run it as an admin, sometimes the client is smart enough to overwrite your script but not when running as admin.